# Exim MySql Bug?

Tags: centos, mysql, exim

In an Authenticator for a outgoing smtp connection I have this:

```
remote_login:
  driver = plaintext
  public_name = LOGIN
  client_send = : user : password
```

And that works fine.

If I switch out the password with:

```
${extract{auth_pass}{${lookup{$sender_address_domain}wildlsearch{/etc/exim/smtp_auths}{$value}fail}}}
```

with a ./smtp_auths

```
example.com: auth_pass=password
```

That still works.

Switch out with a mysql lookup:

```
${lookup mysql{SELECT users.remote_secret as secret FROM users WHERE users.domain='${quote_mysql:$sender_address_domain}'}{$value}}
```

I get the following error in the log when sending.

> defer (-48): Temporary internal error

But using debugging:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-16-5 exim]$ sudo exim -be -Mset <message-id>
> ${extract{auth_pass}{${lookup{$sender_address_domain}wildlsearch{/etc/exim/smtp_auths}{$value}fail}}}
password
> ${lookup mysql{SELECT users.remote_secret as secret FROM users WHERE users.domain='${quote_mysql:$sender_address_domain}'}{$value}}
password
>
```

It really seems like it should work.  Anyone seen this problem before?

Also if I switch out

```
${quote_mysql:$sender_address_domain}
```

with

```
example.com
```

It works. So I know mysql is working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this mail list posting](https://lists.gt.net/exim/users/62035), because `client_send`'s value is a list, the `:` characters are used to split the list before any expansion is done, meaning that exim is trying to treat

```
${lookup mysql{SELECT users.remote_secret as secret FROM users WHERE users.domain='${quote_mysql`
```

as one string and

```
$sender_address_domain}'}{$value}}
```

as a second string.

You'll need to double the `:` character in order to escape it and have the entire command treated as a single string:

```
${quote_mysql::$sender_address_domain}
```

Comment: thank you soo much I spend a day on this.  You are the best person in the world right now.